# Remove an object when in a for each loop

Tags: vb.net, loops, object, foreach

I'm making a survival game and trying to remove an object when it goes off the screen. Here is the code:

```
Public Sub tmrEnemyMove_Tick(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles tmrEnemyMove.Tick
    Dim koopaAnimation As Boolean

    For Each enemy As enemy In lstEnemy
        enemy.enemy.Left = enemy.enemy.Left - 20

        If enemy.enemy.Tag = "koopa" Then
            enemy.enemy.Image = Image.FromFile(Application.StartupPath + "\Graphics\koopa" + Trim(Str(koopaPosition)) + ".png")
            If koopaAnimation = False Then
                If koopaPosition = 0 Then
                    koopaPosition = 1
                Else
                    koopaPosition = 0
                End If
            End If
            koopaAnimation = True
        End If

        If picMario.Left < enemy.enemy.Left AndAlso enemy.enemy.Left < picMario.Right Or picMario.Left < enemy.enemy.Right AndAlso enemy.enemy.Right < picMario.Right Then
            If picMario.Top < enemy.enemy.Top AndAlso enemy.enemy.Top < picMario.Bottom Or picMario.Top < enemy.enemy.Bottom AndAlso enemy.enemy.Bottom < picMario.Bottom Then
                'MsgBox("Collision")
            End If
        End If

        If enemy.enemy.Left < 0 Then
            lstEnemy.Remove(enemy)
            Me.Controls.Remove(enemy.enemy)
        End If
    Next
End Sub
```

The error I get is:
An unhandled exception of type 'System.InvalidOperationException' occurred in mscorlib.dll
Additional information: Collection was modified; enumeration operation may not execute.

If anyone could help that would be great, thanks.

Comment: You canot change the collection like this while looping through it, for obvious reasons if you think about it. Get a reference to the object while in the loop, then delete aterwards

Answer (score 15):

You cannot delete an object from a collection during enumeration. You cannot modify the collection at all. That will cause an error (*Collection was modified; enumeration operation may not execute*). But you could add the objects that you want to delete/remove to another collection:

```
Dim removeEnemies = New List(Of enemy)
For Each enemy As enemy In lstEnemy
    ' ... '
    If enemy.enemy.Left < 0 Then
        removeEnemies.Add(enemy.enemy)
    End If
Next

For Each enemy In removeEnemies
    lstEnemy.Remove(enemy)
    Me.Controls.Remove(enemy.enemy)
Next
```

All of the following methods will cause a list to change its version (which is checked during enumeration):

- Add
- Clear
- Insert
- InsertRange
- Remove
- RemoveRange
- RemoveAt
- Reverse
- [the Indexer setter]
- Sort

Another option is to use a `For-Loop` and loop it backwards:

```
 For i As Int32 = lstEnemy.Count - 1 To 0 Step -1
    Dim enemy = lstEnemy(i)
    ' ... '
    If enemy.enemy.Left < 0 Then
        lstEnemy.Remove(enemy)
        Me.Controls.Remove(enemy.enemy)
    End If
Next
```

This will not raise that error but it's not as readable. You need to go from `list.Count - 1` To `0` because you want to remove items which would change the `Count` property and an index that was available before the item was removed causes now an `ArgumentOutOfRangeException`.

Last but not least, you can use  [`List.RemoveAll`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/wdka673a(v=vs.110).aspx):

```
lstEnemy.RemoveAll(Function(enemy) enemy.enemy.Left < 0)
```

Comment: other option is to use a while. great answer

Answer (score 1):

.NET really doesn't like it when you change a collection when you're in the middle of enumerating its contents.  You might try chAnging your `foreach` loop to a `for` loop if you're planning on removing elements from the collection like this.

Answer (score 0):

One example using entity framework (ElementAt(i)):

```
for (int i = 0; i < db.Itens.Count(); i++)
{
    Item item = db.Itens.ElementAt(i);
    if (item.Id == 0) // put a condition
    {
        db.Itens.Remove(item);
        i--;
    }
}
```